# I am canning quart jars of tomato sauce and heard a few "pop" before pressure was reached; is this ok

Tags: food-safety, canning

Is it okay if my lids "pop" before pressure cooking is finished

Comment: Did you hear the "pop" from the jars while they were in the hot water bath?

Answer (score 1):

That means the jars have been sealed, however it’s just one of the safety measures of pressure canning. The other function of pressure canning is to kill the pathogens by exposing the food to high temperatures for a certain time. You should complete the full process to achieve food-safety.